# Execute command after `startxfce4`

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, xfce

I want to execute some command after I started Xfce with `startxfce4` command from tty. After some search, I put those command in a file. But it doesn't work (the file didn't get sourced automatically)! I have tried putting those command on `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.xprofile`, `~/.xsession`, `~/.xsessionrc`, and set executable permission. Still doesn't work. What is the right file to put those command in?

BTW, here's the commands:

```bash
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources &

xset r rate 300 25 &

xinput set-prop "Asus TouchPad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1 &
xinput set-prop "Asus TouchPad" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1 &

source some/file.bash

firefox
```

Comment: Is that command you would like to fire after launching your DE related to your DE / X-server ? If yes then what about firing it thanks to the desktop autostart facilities / within the startx script ? If not then you surely could fire it before starting your DE.

Comment: Uhh actually it was just some hardware setting like the touchpad reverse scroll, keyboard rate etc. But the setting is kind of useless on tty mode :/ so I think it's good to only set that when Xorg has been started (yeah pretty stupid) but thats it

Comment: Aren't these settings possible via xfce4-settings facility ?  https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/start or possible as part of xorg.conf ?

Comment: Yeah now I think that's possible. But I still want to know how to do that with some Xorg file in case I want to execute some command that is not related to setting (open some apps, source some file etc).

Comment: Then please post your file containing these commands as part of your question.

Comment: @manungsa but even if it's a different command, you'd do it with autostart / session management facilities, not through startxfce

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about that. Maybe I need to learn some more. Maybe I just can't express the question better. Thanks for the reply :).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> xset r rate 300 25
> ```

This is related to keyboard's autorepeat settings originally meant to be part of the X-server configuration by adding the

```
Option "AutoRepeat" "delay rate"
```

to the InputDevice section related to your keyboard.

Having this set as above would be equivalent to launch `xset` immediately after launching the X-server and prior to any other X application start.

Of course there is little sense to have that sort of things set before launching whatever DE (and in particular xfce4) since whatever DE is likely to force its own settings in accordance with user's preferences as set as part as some system settings (in particular the [xfce4-settings](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/start))

Therefore, regarding this sort of things, either you want to launch a DE and you consequently want to have this set as part of DE's system settings or you have this set as part of your `xorg.conf`.

---

> ```
> xinput set-prop "Asus TouchPad" "libinput Tapping Enabled"
> xinput set-prop "Asus TouchPad" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled"
> ```

With this, you are willing to tune the behaviour of some device driven by an Xorg input driver based on [libinput](https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput).
You can read in the manual page linked hereabove :

> It is recommended that libinput devices are configured through the
> InputClass directive (refer to xorg.conf(5)) instead of manual
> per-device configuration

Therefore, you should prefer setting `Option "Tapping" "1"` and `Option "NaturalScrolling" "1"` as part of the appropriate `InputDevice` section of some `xorg.conf`.

There again, your DE is likely to override these settings, [in particular considering xfce4](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/mouse#touchpad).

---

> ```
> firefox
> ```

Of course you do not want that sort of things to be launched "in the back" of your DE. Then if you want it to be launched automatically at DE starts, then you need to resort to your DE's *autostart* capabilities.
[Regarding xfce4 in particular](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/preferences#application_autostart).